# Menu button (three points) black with black action bar on Android 4

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a very strange problem. If I run my app on an Android 4 emulator, the menu button (three point) is render in black color, and my action bar is black too. Then, I can't see the button, but I can push it and the menu is showed.
If I change my emulator to Android 5 or higher, the three points are painted in grey color and then I can see the icon.

This is part of my style.xml:

```
<style name="app_theme2" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_green_500</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/light_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/light_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/light_green_500</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

My activities are extended from AppCompatActivity and I have added a toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

And on the activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActivityMyActivity.this, R.color.my_white));
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ActivityMyActivity.this, R.color.my_white));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.MyTitleofActivity));
```

I don't know why it happens. I tried it with a device and I get the same behavior. On a device with Android 4, the button is hidden (by color) but I can use it. On a device with Android 5 or higher, the button is painted in gray and the I can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your Style in Style files for your activity.

**see the refrence url:**

https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/

Comment: Thanks. I read the post and I have changed my style.xml to Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (without Light) and now I can see the three dots icons.

Answer (score 0):

Its occur due to the context you use,

Try use `Classname.this` or `getApplicationContext`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Activity's theme from AndroidManifest. And choose custom colors